# RPG character creation implementation

Tags: c#, beginner, console, role-playing-game

This is a little yet unfinished RPG I made with C#. It runs well but I'm wondering if there are things I could improve to make it more clear or optimal.  I'm basically asking for some feedback and suggestions.

The program is obviously not finished but I'm asking now before I move on so I know if I got some serious design or logic issues there. I'm a beginner in programming so keep that in mind when answering.

```
class Main
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.WriteLine("1. New Game\n" +
                          "2. Load Game\n" +
                          "3. Exit Game\n");
        string choice = Console.ReadLine();
        bool correctChoice = false;
        Hero newHero = new Hero();
        while (correctChoice == false)
        {
            switch (choice)
            {
                case "1":

                    CharacterCreation.createChar(newHero);
                    correctChoice = true;
                    break;
                case "2":
                    Console.WriteLine("This feature is not yet implemented.");
                    correctChoice = false;
                    break;
                case "3":
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a correct value.");
                    break;
            }
            if (correctChoice == true)
                break;
            else
                choice = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n Your character is {0}, a {1}.", newHero.heroName, newHero.heroClass);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class CharacterCreation
{
    public static void createChar(Hero newHero)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n We will proceed in character creation.");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your character name:");
        newHero.heroName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("\nNow choose your character's class: \n" +
                          "Warrior......1\n" +
                          "Mage........2\n" +
                          "Rogue........3");
        string classChoice = Console.ReadLine();
        bool correctChoice = false;
        while (correctChoice == false)
        {
            switch (classChoice)
            {
                case "1":
                    newHero.heroClass = "Warrior";
                    correctChoice = true;
                    break;
                case "2":
                    newHero.heroClass = "Mage";
                    correctChoice = true;
                    break;
                case "3":
                    newHero.heroClass = "Rogue";
                    correctChoice = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a correct value.");
                    break;
            }
            if (correctChoice == false)
                classChoice = Console.ReadLine();
            else break;
        }
        Hero.ClassSelect(newHero);
    }
}

class Character
{
    public int charHealth, charMaxHealth, charStr, charInt, charAgi;
}

class Hero : Character
{
    public string heroName, heroClass;
    public int level, experience, gold;

    public static void ClassSelect(Hero newHero)
    {
        newHero.charAgi = 10;
        newHero.charInt = 10;
        newHero.charMaxHealth = 100;
        newHero.experience = 0;
        newHero.gold = 0;
        newHero.level = 1;

        switch (newHero.heroClass)
        {
            case "Warrior":
                newHero.charMaxHealth = newHero.charMaxHealth * 115 / 100;
                newHero.charStr = newHero.charStr * 12 / 100;
                break;
            case "Mage":
                newHero.charInt = newHero.charInt * 12 / 100;
                break;
            case "Rogue":
                newHero.charAgi = newHero.charAgi * 12 / 100;
                break;
        }
        newHero.charHealth = newHero.charMaxHealth;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "optimal"? There doesn't seem to be any performance-sesitive code in your game, so trying to make it faster doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Wel I was wondering if there are probably better ways to write this code, or looking for some serious problems that I wouldn't be aware of.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I haven't done much work in C#, but from a general coding perspective...

```
class Main
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // lotsa stuff....
    }
}
```

These (the class and method both) really ought to be `public`, as I believe that most application runners/executables will be looking for public methods.  Additionally, a `Main()` method should be mostly empty, containing just enough code to launch the rest of the application (whether this submits an additional process or not).

```
 Console.WriteLine()  // Many times
```

Ideally, never call out to the console specifically.  What you should be doing is *injecting* some sort of output/input stream.  It's fine if these actually come from the console, but explicitly tying it to the console itself is frowned upon.

```
Console.WriteLine("1. New Game\n" +
                  "2. Load Game\n" +
                  "3. Exit Game\n");
```

So... you're using `WriteLine()` to write multiple lines at a time?  Seems a little counter-intuitive.  I'm slightly torn between recommending using individual calls (and potentially having output re-ordered because of some threading issue), or just using `Write()`...

```
while (correctChoice == false)
{
    // stuff
}
```

Using booleans like this is frowned upon; don't compare the boolean with a value, use the boolean itself (that's what it's for) - so, it should be `while (!correctChoice) { ... }`.  Additionally, the name is somewhat ambiguous: possibly `availableOptionChosen`?

```
switch (choice)
{
    // lotsa stuff
}
```

Look into something called the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).  While the use of a switch works out for simple things, software patterns are something to always keep in mind.

```
case "2":
    Console.WriteLine("This feature is not yet implemented.");
    correctChoice = false;
    break;
```

Strictly speaking, `correctChoice = false;` shouldn't be necessary.

```
case "3":
    Environment.Exit(0);
    break;
```

Using `Environment.Exic(0);` should end the running thread.  However (if this is anything like Java's `System.Exit()`) this may have unintended consequences.  It would be much better to simply `return` to the next level.

```
default:
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a correct value.");
    break;
```

You check the 'remaining' cases.  Good; generally speaking, you should *always* do so, even if it's impossible (some of those should maybe only be 'asserts', used for verification-time checks).

```
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

You read a line immediately before the program exits.  Why?

```
class CharacterCreation
{

     // Lotsa stuff
}
```

This is semantically a [Builder-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), so the class name is a little odd - perhaps `CharacterCreator`?

```
public static void createChar(Hero newHero) 
{
    // Stuff
}
```

Why the abbreviation of 'Character' (and why all the abbreviations, generally)?  Also, if it's named 'create...', you shouldn't be passing it in - it should be the return type (alternatively, call it `setupCharacter()`, and pass in the `Hero`). Additionally, `newHero` is an awkward name here - just use `hero` (you don't have an `oldHero you're using, do you?).

```
while (correctChoice == false)
{
    switch (classChoice)
    {
```

The stuff I mentioned about your main loop applies here as well.  This is especially prevalent with the class, if you're eventually going for something like DnD (which can have hundreds of classes).

```
class Character
{
    public int charHealth, charMaxHealth, charStr, charInt, charAgi;
}
```

Always put member definitions on their own lines.  Always make them private, and provide equivalent [public properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  Don't abbreviate unnecessarily, seek to be understandable.  Don't prefix variable names with their enclosing class' name (especially abbreviated) - it's noise.

```
class Hero : Character
{
     // Acceptable
}
```

This works, although it may become awkward in the future.

```
public static void ClassSelect(Hero newHero)
{
    newHero.charAgi = 10;
    newHero.charInt = 10;
    newHero.charMaxHealth = 100;
    newHero.experience = 0;
    newHero.gold = 0;
    newHero.level = 1;

    switch (newHero.heroClass)
    {
        case "Warrior":
            newHero.charMaxHealth = newHero.charMaxHealth * 115 / 100;
            newHero.charStr = newHero.charStr * 12 / 100;
            break;
        case "Mage":
            newHero.charInt = newHero.charInt * 12 / 100;
            break;
        case "Rogue":
            newHero.charAgi = newHero.charAgi * 12 / 100;
            break;
    }
    newHero.charHealth = newHero.charMaxHealth;
}
```

This, though, belongs in `CharacterCreation` (that's what it's there for).  Additionally, instead of

```
newHero.charXxx = newHero.charXxx * 12 / 100;
```

you should probably just be setting it to the desired value.  Especially because that's probably a bug, since a warrior will start out with a higher Int (10) than a mage

```
((10 * 12) / 100) = 120 / 100 = 1.2 -> 1
```

which I doubt is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for this reply, very clear and complete, I'll try to fix the code and keep all those things in mind when I'm working on this project.

Comment: “the `break;` shouldn't be necessary” In C#, you can't have fall-through `case`s, so the `break` is actually necessary.

Comment: @svick - I think something might have been copied wrong (or something), especially given the next sentence.  Especially since the `break` is necessary for program flow anyways, much less C#'s syntax requirements.  Also, I dislike fall-through anyways...

Comment: Re: `Always put member definitions on their own lines. Always make them private, and provide equivalent public properties.` - I find it much simpler to not use members at all, and simply have automatic properties with private setters.  `public int Health { get; private set; }`

Answer (score 3):

Your code is "incorrect" in quite a few ways, from naming conventions, to separation of concerns (UI vs. object creation) to bedrock principles (such as principle of least privilege - `public` member variables being a big no-no). All that being said, I've taken a quick stab at addressing some of those I've listed above:

```
using System;

internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.WriteLine("1. New Game\n" +
                          "2. Load Game\n" +
                          "3. Exit Game\n");
        var choice = Console.ReadLine();
        var correctChoice = false;
        Hero newHero = null;
        while (!correctChoice)
        {
            switch (choice)
            {
                case "1":
                    newHero = CharacterCreation.CreateCharacter();
                    correctChoice = true;
                    break;
                case "2":
                    Console.WriteLine("This feature is not yet implemented.");
                    break;
                case "3":
                    return;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a correct value.");
                    break;
            }

            if (!correctChoice)
            {
                choice = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n Your character is {0}, a {1}.", newHero.HeroName, newHero.HeroClass);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

internal enum HeroClass
{
    Unknown,

    Warrior,

    Mage,

    Rogue
}

internal static class CharacterCreation
{
    public static Hero CreateCharacter()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n We will proceed in character creation.");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your character name:");

        var heroName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("\nNow choose your character's class: \n" +
                          "Warrior......1\n" +
                          "Mage........2\n" +
                          "Rogue........3");

        var classChoice = Console.ReadLine();
        var correctChoice = false;
        var heroClass = HeroClass.Unknown;

        while (!correctChoice)
        {
            switch (classChoice)
            {
                case "1":
                    heroClass = HeroClass.Warrior;
                    correctChoice = true;
                    break;
                case "2":
                    heroClass = HeroClass.Mage;
                    correctChoice = true;
                    break;
                case "3":
                    heroClass = HeroClass.Rogue;
                    correctChoice = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a correct value.");
                    break;
            }

            if (!correctChoice)
            {
                classChoice = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        return Hero.ClassSelect(heroName, heroClass);
    }
}

internal class Character
{
    private readonly int health;

    private readonly int maxHealth;

    private readonly int strength;

    private readonly int intelligence;

    private readonly int agility;

    protected Character(int health, int MaxHealth, int strength, int intelligence, int agility)
    {
        this.health = health;
        this.maxHealth = MaxHealth;
        this.strength = strength;
        this.intelligence = intelligence;
        this.agility = agility;
    }

    public int Health
    {
        get
        {
            return this.health;
        }
    }

    public int MaxHealth
    {
        get
        {
            return this.maxHealth;
        }
    }

    public int Strength
    {
        get
        {
            return this.strength;
        }
    }

    public int Intelligence
    {
        get
        {
            return this.intelligence;
        }
    }

    public int Agility
    {
        get
        {
            return this.agility;
        }
    }
}

internal sealed class Hero : Character
{
    private readonly string name;

    private readonly HeroClass @class;

    private readonly int level, experience, gold;

    public Hero(string name, HeroClass @class, int maxHealth, int strength, int intelligence, int agility)
        : base(maxHealth, maxHealth, strength, intelligence, agility)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.@class = @class;
        this.experience = 0;
        this.gold = 0;
        this.level = 1;
    }

    public string HeroName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }
    }

    public HeroClass HeroClass
    {
        get
        {
            return this.@class;
        }
    }

    public int Level
    {
        get
        {
            return this.level;
        }
    }

    public int Experience
    {
        get
        {
            return this.experience;
        }
    }

    public int Gold
    {
        get
        {
            return this.gold;
        }
    }

    public static Hero ClassSelect(string name, HeroClass @class)
    {
        var maxHealth = 100;
        var strength = 0; // this is not set anywhere in your original code.
        var intelligence = 10;
        var agility = 10;

        switch (@class)
        {
            case HeroClass.Warrior:
                maxHealth = maxHealth * 115 / 100;
                strength = strength * 12 / 100;
                break;
            case HeroClass.Mage:
                intelligence = intelligence * 12 / 100;
                break;
            case HeroClass.Rogue:
                agility = agility * 12 / 100;
                break;
        }

        return new Hero(name, @class, maxHealth, strength, intelligence, agility);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this reply as well, I'll see how I can incorporate those elements in my code.

Comment: Just echoing my comment on the other answer, because it applies here too (even moreso) - I find it much simpler and easier to read to have automatic properties with private setters than private fields exposed by public get-only properties.

Comment: @Bobson I would certainly agree, except in the case where the values are intended to be frozen after initialization (`readonly` for the backing fields). Automatic properties don't give that option to signify the intent. It's a bit lamentable that it's not the case given today's push for parallel processing and the associated desire for immutable objects where applicable.